# Bash command with argument stream

Tags: bash

I look for a manner to provide a bash command with multiple arguments only by some syntax sugar. I already know $@ and $*, but I do not know how to use them properly. It would be nice with the following syntax:

```
define args
command &args
```

A further syntax can be as follows:

1. Concatenate single and stream arguments in a row

```
define args_stream
command &args_stream arg_1
```

2. Concatenate single and stream alternatively

```
define args_stream1
define args_stream2
command &args_stream arg_1 &args_stream2
```

It seems kind of a bad practice, but I wish to reduce some rows of my shell scripts... :(

**Update**
Examples: Since the question is so broad that the readers could not grasp its actual meaning, I provide examples:

1. My [`printHeader` function](https://github.com/brunolnetto/engage/blob/1c89cb847f542a59cc361f816267c6ce792e3b16/setup.sh#L164) has 7 arguments, but most of them may be parametrized. One option is to set my variable to some default parameter. However, I would have to order the arguments in an unusual form, for main arguments as the most right elements. Other form is to write the arguments as I mention: I would like to right these arguments, stream or array, as I mention as below:

```
command $1 [$2.1 $2.2 $2.3] $3
```

2. By run of command `git --help`, I receive the log below:

```
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | -P | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
```

Arguments between brackets are optional, but may be provided by double hyphen `--` notation. It is an option for my argument stream notation.

Comment: As I read your question I see nothing that has anything to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Personally, I think you're going about it wrong.  You've decided on `bash` and are asking how one would do what you suggested with `bash`.  Using your point #2 with `git` as an example, I don't consider myself an expert in `bash`, but if I had to do that, I definitely wouldn't use `bash`.  If `git` were a C++ program, I'd use Boost's [program options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/program_options.html).  I'm not saying you can't do it with `bash`, but I don't expect it to be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're talking about `$1`, `$2`, and so on, into a script where you can let's just say, `youtube-dl argument1 argument2`.

```
$ command argument1 argument2
```

Where `$1` and `$2` represent those arguments.

Or,

There are also other ways to do it so:

```
command="proot"
command+=" --link2symlink"
command+=" -0"
command+=" -r $folder"
```

As examples.

> Since the question is still unclear to me, let me know before for edit or deleting this answer appropriately.

Comment: In case one want to write args [$1 $2] like in python language instead of separated $1 $2

Comment: not really because in my example is a bash script

Comment: But is it possible or may I have to encapsulate it in some other function?

Comment: your question is very confuse and not specific, that happens when we don't understand well a topic. I'm sure your problem is real but needs clear direction

Comment: It seems my case may be solved by xargs. But I appreciate the effort to solve my issue. :)